# How to keep the shortcuts of a hidden widget in PyQt5?

Tags: qt, pyqt5

I have a menu bar with a shortcut associated to it. I want to hide the menu bar but in that case the associated shortcut will be disabled. Here is an example:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QAction

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.InitWindow()

    def InitWindow(self):
        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu("&File")

        mainMenu.hide()    # comment it and the shortcut 'q' will work

        quitItem = QAction("Quit", self)
        quitItem.setShortcut("Q")
        quitItem.triggered.connect(self.close)

        fileMenu.addAction(quitItem)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

If you put the line `mainMenu.hide()` in a comment, i.e. if the menu bar is shown, then the app. will quit with the shortcut '`q`'. How could I keep the shortcuts of a hidden widget?

In the app. I want to add full-screen support, and in that case I want to hide the menu bar, but also, I want to keep the shortcuts in full-screen mode.

Comment: Why not create another shortcut associated with the main window and perform the same action? The Shorcuts are dependent on the visibility of the widget so you have that problem.

Comment: @eyllanesc: If I add it to the main window too, I get a shortcut collision: `QAction::eventFilter: Ambiguous shortcut overload: Q`. I put a short example here: https://pastebin.com/i4HfDsds .

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution. The idea is the following: the main window has a shortcut ('q' in the example), and the menu bar also has this shortcut. To avoid conflict, disable the window's shortcut if the menu bar is present. If the menu bar is hidden, enable the window's shortcut.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QAction, QShortcut

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.shortcutQuit = QShortcut(QKeySequence("q"), self)
        self.shortcutQuit.activated.connect(self.close)
        self.shortcutQuit.setEnabled(False)    # disable it if the menu bar is visible

        self.InitWindow()

    def InitWindow(self):
        self.mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = self.mainMenu.addMenu("&File")

        hideItem = QAction("Hide Menu Bar", self)
        hideItem.setShortcut("h")
        hideItem.triggered.connect(self.my_hide)

        quitItem = QAction("Quit", self)
        quitItem.setShortcut("Q")
        quitItem.triggered.connect(self.close)

        fileMenu.addAction(hideItem)
        fileMenu.addAction(quitItem)

    def my_hide(self):
        self.mainMenu.hide()
        self.shortcutQuit.setEnabled(True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```